# FindRoot, How to Return Null After x Number of Iterations

Tags: equation-solving, functions, numerics

I am using `FindRoot` to find the root of a function, say `f(x)`, and going through a loop for different values of `x`. The function has no root for certain values of `x`, so there is an error which is thrown saying

`"Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations."`

I read that when this happens, Mathematica gives `x` the value at which it was at when the maximum iterations was achieved. Is there a way to make `x` equal to `Null` when the maximum number of iterations is achieved?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Check[FindRoot[f[x], {x, x0}], {x -> Null}]
```

will yield `{x -> Null}` when any error is encountered.  If you wish `Null` only for specific errors, list them in the third argument of `Check`; for instance,

```
Check[FindRoot[f[x], {x, x0}], {x -> Null}, {FindRoot::cvmit}]
```

To silence all error messages too, prepend `Quiet`.

```
Quiet@Check[FindRoot[f[x], {x, x0}], {x -> Null}]
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the best approach is to test the root.

You have

```
x0 = x /. FindRoot[f[x], {x, 1}]
```

or similar.  Then see how close `f[x0]` is to zero and make your judgement on whether to accept or discard the result.  `FindRoot` itself can't do better than that either.  When it says that it can't converge to the desired accuracy, it means that it thinks that `f[x0]` is not close enough to zero.

Providing the result and letting the user decide about it is better than discarding it automatically and preventing us from even seeing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried doing what you suggested, but I was having issues implementing it in my code, which is why I was looking to see if there was a better way of doing it. I will try to fix it. Thanks again!